# Invoking an Ant Target Automatically upon Import

Tags: ant

I have a rather simple question.
we usually do this as a build.xml file for Ant

```
<project default="" name="Caterpillar Common settings">
    <property name="some.name" value="some.value" />
</project>
```

So if we import this one in another .xml project it will set the 'some.name' to 'some.value'.

Some times setting this 'some.name' is a bit complicated and needs some logic that is written inside of couple of small targets.

QUESTION: how can I invoke a target automatically just like the  tag in the top level does?

I tried `<antcall>` and apparently top-level is not its cup of tea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) may be used to call targets in other Ant projects.

> By default, all of the properties of the current project will be available in the new project. Alternatively, you can set the `inheritAll` attribute to false and only "user" properties (i.e., those passed on the command-line) will be passed to the new project. In either case, the set of properties passed to the new project will override the properties that are set in the new project

One way to structure your build, would be to call your subproject first,
which would then call the master project using the `Ant` task.

In the following example, **project2.xml** initializes properties,
which are then used by the master project file **build.xml**.

### project2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project2" default="initialize">
  <dirname property="project2.dir" file="${ant.file.project2}" />
  <property name="caterpillar.dir" location="${project2.dir}" />

  <target name="initialize">
    <property name="some.name" value="some.value" />
    <ant dir="${caterpillar.dir}" antfile="build.xml" target="build" />
  </target>
</project>
```

### build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Caterpillar-Common-Settings">
  <target name="build">
    <echo message="${some.name}" />
  </target>
</project>
```

The build would be initialized from the command line as follows:

```
$ ant -f project2.xml
```

### Output

```
Buildfile: /home/caterpillar/project2.xml

initialize:

build:
     [echo] some.value

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: But this way you called "initialize" target implicitly.
What I had i mind is:
ant target1
ant target2 ...
but i want this
    <ant dir="${caterpillar.dir}" antfile="build.xml" target="build" />
to still be called without me writing it.

Comment: Instead of using targets, have you considered moving your property initialization logic into [MacroDefs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html)?

Comment: yes. Macrodefs do exactly what i want. They invoke some logic regardless of the target executed. And needs not to be called explicitly.
I will give the correct answer to your initial one, even though macrodef is apparently the keyword i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<Sequential>
    <echo message="something" />
</sequential>
```

There is no need for macrodef to encapsulate this.